# Implicit parameters resolution from super trait

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying use implicit parameters to "inject" a dependency into my classes like this:

```
trait Bar {
    def m:String
}

object Bar {
    implicit val objBar = new Bar{ val m = "from object" } 
}

trait FooTrait { 
    def aBar(implicit bar:Bar) = bar
    def go = { aBar.m }
}
```

Here the compiler supplies the implicit argument to `FooTrait` from the implicit val in `Bar`'s companion object. So doing:

```
scala> println((new FooTrait{}).go)
from object
```

Gives me the result I expect. However, if I mix the FooTrait and another trait like:

```
trait SuperFoo {
    implicit val superBar = new Bar{ val m = "from super" }
}
```

The result is the same:

```
scala> println((new FooTrait with SuperFoo).go)
from object
```

I thought that the compiler would look in the `SuperFoo` before trying to resolve the implicit argument by checking `Bar`'s companion object. This [blog post](http://daily-scala.blogspot.se/2010/04/implicit-parameter-resolution.html) states:

> There are very strict rules for which implicit value is to be applied
>   to a implicit parameter. A simple way to think about it is that the
>   "closest" definition will be used. Local scope, enclosing class,
>   parent class, companion object of the desired type.

Am I missing something or is this a known limitation of scalas implicit parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call to `aBar` is defined inside `FooTrait`. When this trait compiles, there is no proper implicits in local scope, enclosing class, or parent class. Compiler doesn't try to re-find implicits when you mix in another trait later. So it just uses default implicit from companion object.

You can get value from `SuperFoo` if you override method `go`:

```
scala> println((new FooTrait with SuperFoo {override def go = {aBar.m}}).go)
from super
```

You can also redefine you class hierarchy to get your implicit from parent trait:

```
trait BarHolder { 
    implicit val superBar: Bar
}
trait FooTrait extends BarHolder { 
    def aBar(implicit bar:Bar) = bar
    def go = { aBar.m }
}
trait DefaultFoo extends BarHolder {
    val superBar = implicitly[Bar]
}
trait SuperFoo extends BarHolder {
    val superBar = new Bar{ val m = "from super" }
}
```

and use it this way:

```
scala> println((new FooTrait with DefaultFoo).go)
from object

scala> println((new FooTrait with SuperFoo).go)
from super
```

Comment: I thought that the compiler generated a new class when doing a mixin like `new FooTrait with SuperFoo` and that `SuperFoo` would be higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: It does, but what if `FooTrait` and `SuperFoo` were already compiled and you have no access to their sources? To achieve what you want, compiler should override method `go`, replace it with almost the same bytecode, where calls `aBar(Bar.objBar)` replaced with `aBar(superBar)`.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it would be difficult, but really cool if it worked! Maybe it's a nice hobby compiler plugin project :)